# Overriding FlaskForm.validate() doesn't let POST request through

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

SUMMARY

I'm trying to store 3 float values besides a String value; but before that i would like to validate FloatFields by checking each with every other.

They are 3 indicators - Good, Average and Poor and I've included the validators.NumberRange to be in [-1, 1]. This works fine, so if I enter out of range, the default error message is shown in my template that to enter within -1 and 1

Now I have to validate that Good, Average and Poor indicators are in descending order before adding them to db.

CODE

FORM:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, FloatField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, ValidationError, NumberRange
from .models import Crop


# FORMS RENDERED TO CORRESPONDING WEB TEMPLATES IN DEFINED VIEWS

class CropForm(FlaskForm):
    crop_name = StringField("Crop Name", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=80)])
    good_threshold = FloatField("Good", validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=-1, max=1)])
    average_threshold = FloatField("Average", validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=-1, max=1)])
    poor_threshold = FloatField("Poor", validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=-1, max=1)])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")

    def validate_crop_name(self, crop_name):  # IGNORE THIS
        crop = Crop.query.filter_by(crop_name=str(crop_name.data).casefold().replace(" ", "").capitalize()).first()
        if crop:
            raise ValidationError("Crop with the name already exists")

    def validate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CropForm, self).validate(*args, **kwargs)
        good_input = self.good_threshold.raw_data
        average_input = self.average_threshold.raw_data
        poor_input = self.poor_threshold.raw_data
        if good_input < average_input:
            self.average_threshold.errors.append("Average cannot be more than Good Indicator")
        if good_input < poor_input:
            self.poor_threshold.errors.append("Poor cannot be more Good indicator")
        if average_input < poor_input:
            self.poor_threshold.errors.append("Poor cannot be more Average indicator")
```

When I remove/comment the validate() block in CropForm FORM, I am able to send send the unvalidated values like Good=0.5, Average=0.8, Poor=0.9 to the db, which is what I'm not preferring, as they are not in descending order

When I leave it as it is/uncomment, validate() block in CropForm FORM, send the acceptable values like Good=0.9, Average=0.8, Poor=0.5 and I hit the submit button on template, it is not at all sending the values t the db

MODEL:

```
class Crop(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    crop_name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    good_threshold = db.Column(db.Float)
    average_threshold = db.Column(db.Float)
    poor_threshold = db.Column(db.Float)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.id}.{self.crop_name}"
```

VIEW:

```
@app.route("/crops", methods=["POST", "GET"])
    def crops():
        form = CropForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            crop_info = Crop(crop_name=str(form.crop_name.data).casefold().replace(" ", "").capitalize(),
                             good_threshold=form.good_threshold.data,
                             average_threshold = form.average_threshold.data,
                             poor_threshold=form.poor_threshold.data)
            db.session.add(crop_info)
            db.session.commit()
            flash(f"Thresholds added, check record #{crop_info.id}", 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('crops'))
        records = Crop.query.order_by(Crop.id)
        return render_template('crop_thresholds.html', title="Crop Thresholds", form=form, records=records)
```

Comment: your current code does not contain any `raise ValidationError()`. What is the code you had when you tried it?

Comment: @Aldric. I replaced `self.[poor/average]_indicator.errors.append()` with `raise ValidationError()` with the same message, with the same string message. And still no validation taking place

Comment: I added this 

`def validate(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CropForm, self).validate(*args, **kwargs)`

It's validating but not posting the data to the daatabase

Comment: Have you tried returning `True` for your `validate()` function when the conditions pass? In this case perhaps you will need a flag for `all_okay` and if any of the 3 conditions fail, you can set it to false. At the end of all the checks, you can return `all_okay` (which will be true if all are okay), and the validation should pass

Comment: @Aldric. So far I did this, I printed results to the console after giving inputs;
1. I gave unpreferable values 1.1, 1.2, 1,3 the strings in errors.append() are displayed below the formfields as warnings
2. I gave preferable values 0.8, 0.6, 0.4 and I hit submit, it is not posting to db

`print(super(CropForm, self).validate(*args, **kwargs))
        print(super(CropForm, self).is_submitted())`

Both these gave True and True on the console

Comment: @Aldric, can you tell where I have to pass the validate() return True to post it. I'm seeing the POST request going but the values are not being added to the db.

Console grab: 
True
True
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 20:00:57] "POST /crops HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replacing your validate function to be something like this

```py
def validate(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CropForm, self).validate(*args, **kwargs)
    good_input = self.good_threshold.raw_data
    average_input = self.average_threshold.raw_data
    poor_input = self.poor_threshold.raw_data
    all_okay = True
    if good_input < average_input:
        self.average_threshold.errors.append("Average cannot be more than Good Indicator")
        all_okay = False
    if good_input < poor_input:
        self.poor_threshold.errors.append("Poor cannot be more Good indicator")
        all_okay = False
    if average_input < poor_input:
        self.poor_threshold.errors.append("Poor cannot be more Average indicator")
        all_okay = False
    return all_okay
```

The idea is that the validate function will determine whether the validation should be successful or not depending on whether `True` or `False` is returned. So if any of the if statements fail, `all_okay` will be `False` and validation fails. Otherwise validation should pass and you should be able to continue to enter the `if form.validate_on_submit():` code block

Comment: Works perfectly Aldric, after so many hours, you fixed it. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help